# iOS UIScrollView scrolling detection

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I'm developing kind of `UITextView` copy with customizations. For now I need to implement selection cursors (see screenshot of original `UITextView` below)

[image: UITextView]

As I discovered from `Debug View Hierarchy` Apple developers draw these dots on separate Window to avoid clipping, and when `UIScrollView` starts dragging they move these dots inside `UITextView`, when it stops dragging they move it back to separate window. The only problem with this approach is how can I detect when some of my `TextView` `superview`'s are `UIScrollView` and they start/end scrolling? Setting delegate for each of `UIScrollView`-type `superviews` looks bad and will bring a lot of headache, cause I will need to manage several delegates if needed (and even detect there change). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*
 In your viewDidLoad or where ever you create the UITextView call this :[self checkParentViewOfTextView:textField];
*/

-(void)checkParentViewOfTextView:(UITextView*)txv {
    if ([txv.superview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) { // Check if the superview if UIScrollView
        UIScrollView *superScroll =(UIScrollView*) txv.superview;
        superScroll.delegate = self;// In order to call the delegate methods below
        superScroll.tag = 5; // Set a tag to access the current scrollView at these delegate methods
    }
}
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    //Any scrollView did begin scrolling
    if (scrollView.tag == 5) {
        //Actions for your scrollView
    }
}
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    //Any scrollView did end scrolling
    if (scrollView.tag == 5) {
        //Actions for your scrollView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same scroll view delegate for all UIScrollViews.

```
scrollView1.delegate = self
scrollView2.delegate = self
etc...
```

Just implement the delegate methods and take different action if necessary for each scroll view. Either do this by referencing properties in the class or setting the tag.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView!) {
   if scrollView.tag == 0 {
     // Do stuff
   } else {
     // Do other stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: The question is: what if I have scrollview with a lot of stuff inside (including my textview) and also I need (or anyone else) to use some custom delegate not related to textview?

Comment: What is the custom delegate you are trying to use? Just set your delegate as whatever class you want it to be.